# How to define an endpoint for my Flask app hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I've managed to host my Flask app on GCP' App Engine successfully. The default entry point just runs my `app_folder/flask_app.py` module.

Defined in my flask app are some endpoints, `/slack_endpoint` for example, and I can't seem to get a valid response when hitting them. The set up works when running locally.

Here's my `app.yml` for GCP App Engine:

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3

entrypoint: python -m app_folder.flask_app
service: default

handlers:
- url: /slack_endpoint
  script: app_folder.flask_app
```

I can't find any error logs because nothing happens. I'm developing a slack app and when I send a request to my endpoint from slack all I get is a little error symbol in the UI, so I'm asking more about general set up for the app and the endpoints.

My flask_app.py endpoint definitions:

```
@app.route('/slack_endpoint', methods=["POST"])
def accept_slack_request():
    request_dict = json.loads(request.form.to_dict()["payload"])
    slack_client = slack.Slack()
    response_code = slack_client.parse_slack_request(request_dict)

    return jsonify({"message": response_code}), 200
```

I'll note that the `/` endpoint that is meant to simply display a README.md works fine both locally and when hosted on App Engine.

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    """Present the Documentation"""
    _path = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    with open(f'{_path}/README.md', 'r') as readme:
        content = readme.read()
        return markdown.markdown(content)
```

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I've switched the runtime of my App instance to use the standard Python3.7 environment:

```
service: default
runtime: python37
instance_class: F2

entrypoint: python -m app_folder.flask_app

handlers:
  - url: /slack_endpoint
    script: auto
```

With these settings, all url endpoints are handled appropriately by the app that is launched by the `entrypoint` statement. This solved what I thought was a successful deployment. From there it was a matter of getting permissions to access logging reports and troubleshooting.

Comment: When you say "I can't seem to get a valid response when hitting them", what do you mean? What exactly is the response you get? Can you show the output from `curl` or a similar HTTP request?

Comment: ATM I can't see any response. When developing through with slack you define a URL to send and receive ALL requests and responses, and your app must parse and direct appropriately. The flask app is hosted and the readme index displays when navigating to the base url. I press the button in the Slack UI that triggers the payload to the defined URL + /endpoing but nothing happens. I see no logs on the app side. 

Works locally (when run locally I can inspect local port traffic easily) but I think I'm just not defining my entry point or handlers correctly?

Comment: 1) Include a link to the API documentation that is calling your endpoint. 2) For cases like yours create a test HTTP POST request with a payload that matches what slack sends. Then you can use `curl`, postman, etc. to debug your app by sending requests and analyzing the returned response.

Comment: Could you please make a POST request to your "/slack_endpoint" using curl and show what message are you getting?

Comment: I updated the config for the runtime and was granted access to logging files (housed in different location than error logs) in GCP. In short, I thought my deployment was successful at time of posting but it wasn't, and the updates allowed me to troubleshoot.